# add header to html page in printing by css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

i want to print html page with modern browser and add header on every page on printing. Techniques found on the internet but does not work in modern browsers.
Is there a way to do this?

i add example that not work me in modern browser.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var head = $('table thead tr');
  $( "tbody tr:nth-child(10n+10)" ).after(head.clone());
 });
```

```css
    table{
        border:none;
    }
    tr{
  display:block;
 }
    td, th{
        width: 100px;
    }
 tbody tr.head {
  page-break-before: always;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
 }
 @media screen {
  tbody .head{
   display: none;
  }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table border="1">
  <thead>
   <tr class="head">
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Year</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr class="start">
    <td>January</td>
    <td>2010</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>2010</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>2010</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>April</td>
    <td>2010</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>May</td>
    <td>2010</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>June</td>
    <td>2010</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>2010</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>August</td>
    <td>2010</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>September</td>
    <td>2010</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>October</td>
    <td>2010</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>November</td>
    <td>2010</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="end">
    <td>December</td>
    <td>2010</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
```

Comment: show us your effort first

Comment: @Amit singh i add my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample

Use [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for custom style for screen and print

CSS

```css
@media screen {
   .page-header { display: none; }
   .page-footer { display: none; }
}
```

HTML code

```html
<body>
 <p class="page-header">Page header goes here</p>

  your Webpage main content goes here

 <p class="page-footer">Page footer goes here</p>
</body>
```

Comment: This does not satisfy the question: "add header on every page on printing" as it only adds a header for the first page printed.